# Usage of Context Partitions in Esper

Tags: esper

Im new to Esper and Im having trouble getting a context partitioning working.

I have two Event streams:
- PositionEvent (portfolio, contract, positionAmount)
- ContractEvent (contract, underlying)

The output Im trying to get is the following:

```
| portfolio | underlying | positionAmount |
| A         | X          |            100 |
| A         | Y          |            200 |
| B         | X          |            300 |
| B         | Y          |            400 |
```

To do this, I have created a new schema:

```
create schema PortfolioByUnderlying 
  (portfolio string, underlying string, positionAmount double)
```

And a window defined as follows:

```
create window PortfolioByUnderlyingWindow.std:unique(portfolio, underlying)
  as PortfolioByUnderlying

insert into PortfolioByUnderlyingWindow
select PositionEvent.portfolio as portfolio, 
       ContractEvent.underlying as underlying,
       SUM(positionAmount) as positionAmount    
from PositionEvent.std:unique(contract, portfolio),   
     ContractEvent.std:unique(contract)
where PositionEvent.contract = ContractEvent.contract
group by portfolio, underlying
```

I then have 10s to 100s of clients which all do a simple select on this window, with optionally a filter, e.g.: `select * from PortfolioByUnderlyingWindow where positionAmount > 0`

I get the desired result - but it performs the same (in terms of number of incoming PositionEvent events per second) no matter how many threads I use. I've tried it on a 20 core machine with 20 inbound threads, and I get little to no boost over when I turn off the inbound thread pool.

I read in the performance documentation (http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.2.0/esper-reference/html/performance.html#perf-tips-13) that to deal with this I should be using context partitions. I've followed the example, adding this:

```
create context SegmentByUnderlyingPortfolio 
  partition by portfolio, underlyingId from PortfolioByUnderlying
```

Removing the group by from my insert:

```
insert into PortfolioByUnderlyingWindow
select PositionEvent.portfolio as portfolio, 
       ContractEvent.underlying as underlying,
       SUM(positionAmount) as positionAmount    
from PositionEvent.std:unique(contract, portfolio),   
     ContractEvent.std:unique(contract)
where PositionEvent.contract = ContractEvent.contract
```

And setting the context on my select queries:

```
context SegmentByUnderlyingPortfolio 
select * from PortfolioByUnderlyingWindow where ...
```

This doesn't work however, I get no error, but my listener no longer gets update notifications (I send in 10k PositionEvents and the update method gets called once, and both newEvents and oldEvents are null).

I've tried various variations of this (e.g. putting the context on the window itself), but cannot get any updates.

Am I doing something wrong, or maybe I'm missing the point of context entirely? If context partitions are not the right approach, what else can I do to make better use of all the cores on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Your statements are not associated to the context. I.e. "context SegmentByUnderlyingPortfolio insert into PortfolioByUnderlyingWindow ..." and "context SegmentByUnderlyingPortfolio create window PortfolioByUnderlyingWindow".
From what I can see your EPL is just creating the context and not actually associating any statements so its not used. There are examples in the docs. Make sure all statement define their context with "context xxx ....".
The hash buckets context gives the best performance because the engine doesn't need to check whether a partition exists or not. With the partitioned context you have more overhead as the engine must check whether partitions exist. I'd recommend using a hash segmented context with say 64 partitions.

Comment: In my original queries, yes they are not associated with a context. My question is what do I need to do specifically to add a context to these queries. I followed the example given in the documentation, and the result is that my statement no longer gives any updates.